# Make a filesystem accessible by all users

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, bash, mount

I have mounted a filesystem in a /mnt/storage but how do i make it accessible for all users not only root?

Comment: With accessible, do you mean read-only access or read-write access to everyone?

Comment: seems like a good question for [unix SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) also I'm guessing this depends on how it's mounted. is it a removable drive? what filesystem? nfs? samba?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mount the drive with the `-o noacl` option, everybody will have full read/write access.
If you only want people to be able to read the drive, `chmod a+r /mnt/storage`

Comment: For read-only access you could also use the `ro` option when mounting.

Comment: Got `mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bas superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.` NTFS drive.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the uid & gid options to identify the mounted volume's owner.  In /etc/fstab you can use something like:

```
/dev/sdc1  /mnt/storage  ext4 uid=1000,gid=1000 1 2
```

or interactively:

```
sudo mount -o uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sdc1 /mnt/storage
```

Comment: It's not possible to force an owner on a disk with an ext4 filesystem. Only filesystems which do not support Linux permissions like fat have an attribute for ownership/groupship: uid=value and gid=value. See the manual page on mount.